# My MonoTouch App won't run on 6.1.3, runs on 6.0.x and before... WTF?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I just pushed my app to the App Store after building release/AppStore build using xamarin's Studio...

Everything was green lighted and ready to go, I only had one person who had not installed the release version....  They installed it and it takes 17 seconds to try to start and is killed (I presume). it does NOT create a crash log on the device.

In the Settings there is a "Debug Settings" section under the app - that *I* didn't put there, including an option for Xamarin Studio Host which is set to automatic but appears to be able to be set to some other string..  (Another message on what the heck this is, and how come it shows up in the first place, and how to get rid of it)

I'm at a loss how to debug this.  I just downloaded and upgraded XCode to the latest, in hopes that will help.. (Although, I'm not using the XCode interface to build, but I expect that under the hood it is using that for parts of this, maybe the libraries or something.)  Still, unless the iOS writers are nuts, it should be backward compatible with apps written for iOS 4.0 and later...  (Mine is a 4.0 targeted app)

Also, on her phone (which has always been 6.x for all the testing she has done), my app has always taken a LONG time to start up.. but on 5.1 it is very fast.. (I.E. 1-2 seconds vs 10+ seconds on her phone)

Anyone got a clue, I sure could use one right now.. I expect that I'll have to reject the binary, and submit another one...

-Chert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.... The issue was with the TestFlightApp SDK...

I removed it and now the app starts up OK...  Resubmitted to App Store for approval.